# Creating activities automatically from phone calls, other interactions

Tags: mobile, civimobile, civicontact

Looking for suggestions on how to streamline the creation of activities for ad-hoc interactions with contacts while staff is on the go.

Re. phone calls, I expect CiviMobile and CiviContact already offer to create an activity after they launch a call. Hopefully prepopulating participants, time, and duration. Does either offer the same for inbound calls? Is there a way to approximate it?

Similar wish list for SMS. We have the ability to send SMS messages from CiviCRM, but receiving is clunky (inbounds turn into emails) and responding via the CiviCRM web pages is cumbersome on a phone.

Emails are not that different, we can send emails from the CiviCRM web pages but most threads end up conducted directly in the staffer's GMail app. CiviCRM can monitor an inbox and create activities from there, but that's only one email address not one per staff member.  An attempt to get staff to remember to bcc the inbox CiviCRM monitors in all their emails didn't go well!

Penny for your thoughts.